# How can I find out when a dataset was allocated?

Tags: mainframe

I need to get the exact time when a dataset was allocated (not opened). I've searched all the SMF records but can't find anything suitable. Any ideas? It was allocated via SVC99 from a vendor STC. I'm pretty sure it's allocated and then OPENed, as the first SMF record referencing the dataset is DISP=OLD.

The dataset is not SMS managed.

Comment: If you happen to have security auditing enabled, you may find an answer in the security audit trail...although the specifics vary depending on whether you have RACF, ACF2 or Top Secret, the system does a resource check on the volume, followed by a resource check on the dataset name itself. In Top Secret, for example, these would both be done with "CREATE" access levels, making it pretty easy to find when the dataset was originally allocated (and by whom). Only catch is that you need this level of access logging enabled, so it's a bit of a long shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are out of luck.

To my knowledge, creation time is not an attribute of any dataset. So looking through the SMF records probably wont help. You might be able to get the time of the first action perform after allocation, but that doesn't sound like it will help you. I found a thread on the IBM Mainframe forum that basically confirms my thought.

It says:

> The only way to get the creation time of a data set is through
>   analyzing SMF data for the date the data set was created, the creation
>   time is not an attribute of the data set.
>
> I'm not even certain you could get the time that way as no SMF data is
>   written when the data set is created. The best you can do is the time
>   the first I/O to the data set completes and a type 15 SMF record is
>   written.

Comment: thanks - I think I've come to the same conclusion. I have a DF/SORT job to analyse SMF records and I can show when the dataset was cataloged and an OPEN/CLOSE/DELETEs etc. We Use CA Allocate for our DASD management and I think you can code an exit to write an SMF record to do it, but that's no help after the event.